# How to find specific video with Pytube?

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to find videos with the word "Proje" in the title from the playlist. I write these but it didn't work.

```
from pytube import Playlist

p = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEcJSEQK_cD5KHgg9sXumeg659hAr2j4W')

for video in p.videos:
    title = video.title
    if "Proje" in title:
        print(title)
```

Comment: use the find() method for research in title.find("Proje")

Comment: what is the errors you are facing? your code does the work it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the library?

```
pip install pytube
```

Your code gives this out:

```
Java Dersleri #5- Proje Oluşturma ve IDE'ye Genel Bakış
Java Dersleri #15 - Proje :  Not Ortalaması Hesaplayan Program
Java Dersleri #16 - Proje : KDV Hesaplayan Program
Java Dersleri #17 - Proje : Dairenin alanını ve çevresini bulan program
Java Dersleri #22 - Proje : Hesap Makinesi Yapımı
Java Dersleri #23 - Proje : Kullanıcı Girişi
Java Dersleri #24 - Proje : Not Ortalamasına Göre Sınıf Geçme
Java Dersleri #25 - Proje : Uçak Bilet Fiyatı Hesaplayan Program
Java Dersleri #26 - Proje : Etkinlik Öneren Program
Java Dersleri #27 - Proje : Sayıları Büyükten Küçüğe Sıralayan Program
Java Dersleri #32 - Proje : While Örnekleri 1
Java Dersleri #33 - Proje : While Örnekleri 2
Java Dersleri #39 - ATM Projesi
Java Dersleri #44 - Metotlar Proje : Palindrom Sayılar
Java Dersleri #45 - Recursive Proje : Fibonacci Serisi
Java Dersleri #54 - Proje : Dizideki Elemanların Ortalaması
Java Dersleri #55 - Proje : Sayı Tahmin Oyunu
Java Dersleri #56 - Proje : Palindromik Kelimeler
Java Dersleri #57 - Proje : Mini Mayın Tarlası Oyunu
```

but you can do:

```
lista = []

for video in p.videos:
    title = video.title
    lista.append(title.find('Proje'))
    
for x in lista:
   print(x)
```